# How to display the model coded in cplex in java?

Tags: java, cplex

I have a code of a mathematical optimization model in CPLEX in Java. I wonder if there is a way in java to get output of the model format in java like "CPXwriteprob" in C++?

Comment: I have coded stochastic programming model. It is a big one. I have generated so many scenarios and they will be input to my mathematical model. For some reason the model is infeasible. I need to display the model I have coded to make sure I have coded the model correctly. In this case the problem must come from scenarios. I have been working on this for a while and at this point I feel so frustrated. Please if you know how can I display the model in cplex in java, help me with that. thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, like is discussed in a similar question asked at almost the same time in [How to check whether the model coded in CPLEX in .NET is the true model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447636/how-to-check-whether-the-model-coded-in-cplex-in-net-is-the-true-model), you need to use the exportModel() function. You can see this in several of the provided CPLEX examples, such as LPex1.java:

```
// write model to file
cplex.exportModel("lpex1.lp");
```

Secondly, in C++ it would be more normal to use exportModel() that has exactly the same style and syntax as the Java version. The function CPXwriteprob() is the (lower-level) C function

Answer (score 2):

If you define cplex as your object as:

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();// cplex as an object
```

then you can use the method exportModel i.e.:

```
cplex.exportModel("file_name.lp");
```