# How to check whether the model coded in CPLEX in .NET is the true model?

Tags: c#, .net, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I coded an MIP in CPLEX with C#. I declared variables and constraints and added the objective but I cannot get the correct answer. Is there a way to print the model into a string variable or something like in order to check whether I coded correctly the model I had in mind?

Answer (score 4):

You could try exporting it in CPLEX LP format, that is human readable.

I use neither CPLEX nor .NET, but according [this website](http://yalma.fime.uanl.mx/cplex11-manual/refdotnetcplex/html/ILOG.CPLEX.Cplex.ExportModel.html) the function you are looking for is:

> LOG CPLEX .NET Reference Manual    `Cplex.ExportModel` Method
>
> Writes the active model to the file specified by filename.
>
> `public virtual void ExportModel(    String name );`
>
> Parameters
>
> `name`
>       The name of the file to which the model is written. The extension of the filename determines the format in which to write the model
>   file.
>
> Remarks
>
> The file format is determined by the extension of the filename. The
>   following extensions are recognized on most platforms:
>
> ```
> .sav
> .mps
> .Lp
> [...]
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is correct. You can also look at the C# examples provided with CPLEX, such as LPex1.cs which does this:

Comment: Thank you. I found the ExportModel method from the dcoumentation as well. I looked around a little more and I found out that the ToString  methods dumps all the constraints into a string variable that's what I was looking for so thank you.

Comment: @user3599645 I am glad if you find the answer helpful. Here at Stackoverflow we don't say thank you, we accept or upvote the answer if we find it helpful. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157577) In any case, good luck!